# Heroku Toolbelt Installation on Centos 6.5

Tags: heroku, centos

I'm trying to get Heroku Toolbelt installed on our CentOS server, and I can't seem to figure it out. I have ruby and rubygems installed and functioning, and I ran the stand-alone download from the heroku getting started tutorial

```
wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

Running 'whereis heroku', I get

```
heroku: /usr/local/heroku
```

and 'which heroku' outputs

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
```

However, when I try and run 'heroku login', I get

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku
/usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:13:in `home_directory': undefined method `home' for Dir:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:22:in `updated_client_path'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/updater.rb:170:in `inject_libpath'
    from /usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku:19
```

I'm unable to find this same error for heroku on the Google, and I'm not really sure what this error means. Thank you for your help!

### UPDATE 6/22/15

Adding software versions

```
Centos: 6.5
Ruby: 1.9.3
Gems: 2.4.8
```

After upgrading to Ruby 1.9.3, I now get a different error.

Running "which heroku" now gives me the following error                   `which heroku
/usr/bin/which: no heroku in (/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/hugmungus/bin)`

### UPDATE 6/23/15

I've attempted to add this to my path using the following steps from this [SF question](https://serverfault.com/questions/102932/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos), but I'm still getting the same error when running 'Which heroku'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, finally got it working. Here are the steps I took:

### STEP 1

Following Jeff Dickey's suggestion, I took a look and tried to install a newer version of ruby (1.8.4 -> 1.9.3), however, using the wget method was not giving me good results. As such, I used RVM to update to 2.1.0 [using this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-2-1-0-on-centos-6-5-using-rvm), here are the actual steps to get Ruby installed

Download development tools

```
yum groupinstall -y 'development tools'
```

Install RVM

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

If you get an error about a missing public key, run the first suggestion from the installer and then re-run the curl command

```
gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

Add RVM to system path

```
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

Reload RVM to ensure it's in the path, and install ruby

```
rvm reload
rvm install 2.1.0
```

After that, ruby is installed.

### STEP 2

Add Heroku to the system path, I used [this server fault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/102932/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos) to accomplish this

Find Heroku location

```
whereis heroku
```

Add to the path

```
echo 'pathmunge <your heroku install path>' > /etc/profile.d/her.sh
```

Open permissions to allow execute

```
chmod +x /etc/profile.d/ree.sh
```

Log out, and log back in, and that's it. You can run this command after you login to verify it has been added to the path.

```
echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

you're probably on an old version of ruby, update to 1.9 or above

Comment: we were on 1.8.4, but now we're on 1.9.3 (I also upgraded gems after this). Upgrading the Ruby version produced a different error, please see the edit above. I've also added the current software version we're using to my question.

Comment: whoops, sorry about that, I edited my question to show the full error